# SQOOP Import Fails, File Not Found Exception

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am new to hadoop architectures system and installed components using web search. For this i installed Hadoop, sqoop, hive. Here is directory structure for my installations (my local ubuntu machine instead and any vm, Each my installation is on separate directory):-

- /usr/local/hadoop
- /usr/local/sqoop
- /usr/local/hive

**By looking at error i tried to resolve it and so i copied sqoop (local machine /usr/local/sqoop) folder to hdfs directory (hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/local/sqoop). This resolved my problem. I want to know certain things from this:-**

- Before coping my sqoop to hdfs, is my installation right?
- Is it necessary to copy sqoop directory from ext file system to hdfs file system.

> 16/07/02 13:22:15 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/local/sqoop/lib/avro-mapred-1.7.5-hadoop2.jar
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:269)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:390)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:483)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:118)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem with the installation, there is no need to copy all the files from sqoop directory just copy the sqoop library files into hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a directory structure in hdfs which is same as $SQOOP_HOME/lib.

  Example:`hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /usr/lib/sqoop`
- Copy all sqoop library files from $SQOOP_HOME/lib to hdfs lib

  Example:`hdfs dfs -put /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/* /usr/lib/sqoop/lib`